# SVG issue with Glide using Shorthand Hexadecimal Colors

Tags: android, svg, android-glide, androidsvg

I’d like to render SVG assets which use the short hex format as fill color and just discovered the following issue with Glide (4.9.0): [#3094 (comment)](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3094#issuecomment-390356207)

Can I set Glide to accept the short hex colors or is there a workaround to avoid changing every SVG file to the six digits hex format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using AndroidSVG for the SVG rendering. At least that's what the Glide example uses.
Make sure you are using AndroidSVG 1.3 or later. There was a bug in v1.2  with three-digit colour parsing.

http://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/release-1.3.html